# MicrosoftVisual C++ 2015 Redistributable installation failed 0x80240017

Tags: visual-c++, wamp

When I try to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable, I get this error 
0x80240017, I need it to solve the api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll problem

Comment: I need it to instal wamp

Comment: Use Google to find help, query "how to diagnose install error 0x80240017".  The first usable hit is [this superuser.com question](http://superuser.com/questions/979546/vc-redist-x86-exe-setup-failed-0x80240017-unspecified-error), posted by somebody that knew how to read a log file.  Also the site to find more help with problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently, I needed to use XAMPP and when initializing the Apache module I received this error. I tried many things:

- Install all windows updates.
- Install Visual C ++ 2015 Redistributable that installs this DLL (I get this error 0x80240017 and could not install).
- Install the KBKB2999226 and KB2919355 package that contains this DLL.
- Clear TEMP folder and rename directories.

  I could not by any means. What solved my problem was to install Visual Studio 2015 itself, I had to push the envelope, I had to push it, that solved my problem, and XAMPP becomes to run, unfortunately.